# Why does ReadProcessMemory always return zeros?

Tags: c#, winapi, memory, interop, kernel32

Given the code below, ReadProcessMemory always returns an array of zeros. I'm trying to locate a string (which may be numeric) in a running process and identify all the locations where that string exists. But ReadProcessMemory always returns an array of zeros.  Why is that?

- I've tried running VS as administrator and removing the unsafe block.
- processPointer has a correct value for the process handle.
- BaseAddress does correctly iterate by one, and *appears* to be the memory location I'm looking for.
- Despite obviously not finding any matches, it does run fairly quickly. Several seconds for a 72MB process.

.

```
// (other stuff in method...)
IntPtr baseAddress = process.MainModule.BaseAddress;
IntPtr lastAddress = baseAddress + process.MainModule.ModuleMemorySize;
processPointer = OpenProcess((uint)(0x0020), 1, (uint)PID);
for (int addr = (int)baseAddress; addr + value.Length < (int)lastAddress; addr++)
{
    string ActualValue = ReadMemory((IntPtr)addr, (uint)value.Length, (IntPtr)addr);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ActualValue)) continue;
    if (ActualValue.Trim().ToLower() == value.Trim().ToLower())
        PossibleAddresses.Add((IntPtr)addr);
}
// (other stuff in method...)

CloseHandle(processPointer);

private string ReadMemory(IntPtr memAddress, uint size, IntPtr  BaseAddress)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    IntPtr bytesRead;
    unsafe
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(processPointer, BaseAddress, buffer, size, out bytesRead);
        return BitConverter.ToString(buffer); // always "00-00-00-00....."
    }
    return Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer); // Another way I tried to read the data
}


[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(UInt32 dwDesiredAccess, Int32 bInheritHandle, UInt32 dwProcessId);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern Int32 CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern Int32 ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, [In, Out] byte[] buffer, UInt32 size, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);
```

Comment: You aren't checking the return value of `ReadProcessMemory`. If there is an error, it will return `FALSE` and you will need to check `GetLastError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was opening the handle with the wrong access type. 0x0010 is to read; 0x0020 is to write.  I was hoping to get read/write with one open, but it looks like I'll have to handle that separately.

source: http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=15680

Comment: Its easily possible to get read and write on one process handle open, i generally use the `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` flag for this, but using 0x30 should do the trick(`PROCESS_VM_READ|PROCESS_VM_WRITE`), OFC you need sufficient privilages for this, but can be done with `SeSetDebugPrivilages`